# Structuring api urls when using group by

Tags: php, api, rest, url

I have two entities: a channel and a lead. One channel has many leads.
I need to draw a bar chart with channels and how many leads they have. So, for example, "Facebook: 1000 leads, Twitter: 500 leads etc".

I want to get the data using some kind of api (since I'll have a lot of different charts).

What is the restful way to structure the url? `/api/channels` returns all channels, `/api/channels/5/leads` returns leads for the channel with id = 5. But what if I need to retrieve grouped data? For example a list of arrays with channel name and leads num. I guess `/api/channels/leadStats` is not considered as best practice

Answer (score 0):

One application should have one bounded context. It means your navigation or search should start with one type of entity in your application context not multiple ways. You can consider "channel" as your bounded context or "lead" as you bounded context for your service. If you consider "channel" as your bounded context then all retrievals should start with channel.

```
/channels
/channels/{id}
/channels/{id}/leads
/channels/{id}/leads/{id}
```

So to answer your question, I think the first url "/channel" can solve your problem. It will returns all channels and each channel will have the list of leads. You can do the necessary calculation on client side to retrieve the data you need to generate the report you wish.

Comment: So, you suggest to do the calculation on client side, right? Okay, but I got one more question: first I call /channels to get the channel list. Then I need to get leads for all channels. I can include leads as "subentity" in the /channels request, so each json array will contain lead array. But the problem is that if I got 10k leads for each channel, then the /channels request will have quite big response, and sometimes I don't need all the data. If I return only basic info, without leads, then I'll need to make multiple requests for each channel (channels/5/leads) - doesn't seem to be good

Comment: So, what I thought of: /channels?includeLeads=1 for full info, when I need to draw charts and /channels without includeLeads for basic info. However I'm a little bit confused about calculation on the client side, since SQL query looks much easier then grouping the data in javascript. Maybe the other solution is to return leadsNum in the /channels response?

Comment: What I can suggest here to avoid large size response for /channel is instead of keeping all the leads details , just keep the id or ref to get leads in it.

Comment: I think basic rule is REST api will just provide you data in a generic structure and you js/mobile/web app will use that data in their own way. If you find difficult to manipulate that data from /channel  then add a new point your REST api which will provide data in your own way as you mentioned or try to fit additional data you need in the response for /channel.